# Backface not drawn even with CULL_FACE disabled

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm projecting a building in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android and have the strange behaviour, that some walls are only shown in a specific angle. This problem probably occurs because of Backface-Culling. So I deactivated it in onSurfaceCreated of my Renderer:

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

However the error still exists. Some triangles aren't drawn. If I rotate my view by 180 degrees, these triangles are finally drawn and others disappear.

Quick question: Is there anything else I should take care of to display every triangle from both sides?

The only thing I could think of is:

```
GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
```

My triangles simply get a color from the fragment_shader. Maybe I have to change something in this shader?

```
private final String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;"
        + "uniform vec4 vColor;" + "void main() {"
        + "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" + "}";
```

In case more sourcecode is required I'll upload it. Thought that this is not a problem of my implementation but of my lack of knowledge in OpenGL ;)

Screenshots:

There you can see a simple rotation. The whole building should have light gray walls.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Because you've disabled depth test too your triangles can be obscured by other triangles placed further. Without depth test triangles are just drawn on screen in order they are passed to GPU disregarding depth in scene. That might cause them to be covered by other triangles at certain angles and remain visible at other. Try to enable depth test. Also, a screenshot will be worth a thousand words in this case.

Comment: thank you! I'll have a try and also do some screenshots!

Comment: I've just added the pictures. Unfortunately, enabling the depth test didn't make any difference.

Comment: Nope, thats actually everything which I needed for the setup... It's simple drawing of triangles

Comment: This is definitely a depth buffer issue. Right now, two things come to mind: 1) Does your pixel format have a depth buffer? 2) Are you passing correct values for zNear and zFar when you create your projection matrix?

Comment: Hi, I haven't done anything with depth buffers. I thought they would just use the z-coordinate? My zNear is 1f, my zFar is 20f at the moment. Anything wrong with this? Would it help if I make a short example and upload it on Github? Cheers and Thanks!

Comment: Hey, 
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST); did the trick!